# Call function in a object that has parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to programming so forgive me if the follow code is really dumb...

```
var objArray = new Array;

addObject('name',repeat);

function addObject(cName,cFunction){
    objArray.push(new xCommand(cName,cFunction))
}

function xCommand(cName = 'empty',cFunction){
    this.cName = cName;
    this.cFunction = cFunction;
}

function repeat(args = 'no args'){
    console.log(args)
```

(This isnt the actual code in my program but a simplified example)

Basically I'm creating a new object that contains a name and another function. I want to call this function though the object itself later with something like

```
objArray[0].cFunction(argument)
```

I cant seem to figure out how to get this to work correctly. Ive recoded this differently a few different ways but I come into issues with functions being invoked before its called and other random errors.

Comment: You are assigning the function to the property `CFunction`, so it would be `objArray[0].CFunction(argument)`. You can learn more about functions at http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html . **edit:** Now that you have fixed this is in your post, that's a correct way of calling the function. If that doesn't work for you then you have to provide an example which reproduces the issue. See [mcve] for guidance. We cannot help if we don't know which problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could Try this:

```
var objArray = new Array;

addObject('name',repeat);

function addObject(cName,cFunction){
    objArray.push(new xCommand(cName,cFunction))
}

function xCommand(cName = 'empty',cFunction){
    this.cName = cName;
    this.cFunction = cFunction;
}

function repeat(args = 'no args'){
    console.log(args);
    }

objArray[0].cFunction('Argument here');
```